# Changing a part of a JSON request with a variable content

Tags: c#, json

I have a JSON code that request some information to an API, see the following code

```
string json = "{ \"amount\" : \"0.5\", \"withdrawal\" : \"...\", \"pair\" : \"eth_xmr\" }";
```

I actually want to replace that "0.5" information to a variable content I'm getting from some math calculation class.

I tried something but I can't make it work (red line everytime).

How can I replace that "0.5" part to a string variable?

EDIT:

Here is the complete call code:

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{ \"amount\" : \"0.5\", \"withdrawal\" : \"...\", \"pair\" : \"eth_xmr\" }";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
                streamWriter.Flush();
            }
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(responseText);
```

Comment: Why are you creating your JSON by hand? I'd propose using one of the many JSON libraries out there. The "default" one for .NET is JSON.NET.

Comment: I'm using JSON.NET to put the answers into some string variable. I'm just using this to call the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Json.NET and convert your json string and manipulate the amount:

```
string json = "{ \"amount\" : \"0.5\", \"withdrawal\" : \"...\", \"pair\" : \"eth_xmr\" }";

dynamic lsDynObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
lsDynObject.amount = 605.123;
string lsOut = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lsDynObject);

Console.WriteLine(lsOut);
```

Install with:

> Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json

But you have to consider that amount is now a number.
If you keep using amount as a string you have to set:

```
lsDynObject.amount = "605.123";
```

Update:

Use a class like this:

```
public class MyJson
{
    [JsonProperty("pair")]
    public string Pair { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("amount")]
    public string Amount { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("withdrawal")]
    public string Withdrawal { get; set; }
}
```

And write your json with:

```
streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyJson()
{
    Pair = "eth_xmr",
    Withdrawal = "...",
    Amount = "34.676"
}));
```

Comment: Your code is working, but I can't use my variable in amount. Any idea why ?

Comment: Your `amout` variable is probably a number. Convert it to a string or change `MyJson.Amout` to your number type. But If you change to a number type the quotation marks are lost in your json String.

Comment: It's actually a string but I can't make it working in the amount line I don't know why. It's working in a textbox but not in the JSON request.

Comment: Can you add an example in your question?

Comment: I'm actually getting using GET a price coming from an API. This information is saved in a float variable named "USD". I created a method that is calculating the price needed (some math) and in the same method it's converting the float value to a string that is returned. I'm getting the new result from that method under a string value and it's this value I want to use in the JSON request. It's actually working because I can see it in a textbox using the variable but when I'm using it with your code "Amount = variable" it's not working, the API is sending an error. So how can I make it working ?

Comment: Maybe a parsing problem. Check the decimal separator in your string: "." <-> "," Can you post the string you send to api?

Comment: It's a "," ! Didn't noticed it at first, how can I change it to a "." ?

Comment: User `Replace(',','.')`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
double amount = 0.75;
string json = $"{{ \"amount\" : \"{amount}\", \"withdrawal\" : \"...\", \"pair\" : \"eth_xmr\" }}";
```

Don't forget the `$` in front of the string. Then you can access any variable/field/... within the curly braces `{}`

EDIT: You have to use `{{` in the beginning and `}}` in the end to escape the brackets

Comment: @TavishAggarwal It works. You have a syntax error. Did you really downvote it because of that?

Comment: @TavishAggarwal Fair enough.

Comment: Sorry, you have to curly braces in the beginning and the end to escape them

Comment: exactly! you should not be creating json by hand

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using JSON.NET, you should not create your request by hand. Instead compose your JSON object like this:

```
JObject json = new JObject();
json.Add("amount", YourCalculation());
// add your other properties the same way ...
```

If you really need this object as a `string`, you can call `ToString` on it at the end.

Answer (score 0):

While you certainly can manipulate strings to create json, the best way would be to have a model (class) with all those fields, set the values to the model and then serialize it to json before you call the api.